# How do flatten or correctly group by a multiple join

Tags: mysql

**My Structure**

I have three (hypothetical) tables; Users, movies, sessions.

```
> SELECT * FROM users
+----+---------------------------+
| id | email                     |
+----+---------------------------+
|  5 | abcdefghijklmno@gmail.com |
+----+---------------------------+

> SELECT * FROM movies
+----+---------+---------+--------------+
| id |  title  | user_id | total_watches|
+----+---------+---------+--------------+
|  1 |  X-men  |    1    |     1        |
|  2 |  Blade  |    1    |     1        |
|  3 | Goonies |    1    |     1        |
+----+---------+---------+--------------+

> SELECT * FROM sessions
+----+---------+---------+------------+ 
| id | user_id | show_id | total_time |
+----+---------+---------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |       1 |          5 |
|  2 |       1 |       1 |         30 |
|  3 |       1 |       1 |          5 |
+----+---------+---------+------------+
```

**What I want**

I want to get an overview of a user's movie activity in one query, so would like to retrieve the data in the following format:

```
+----+---------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| id | email                     |  total_time   |  total_watches |
+----+---------------------------+---------------+----------------+
|  5 | abcdefghijklmno@gmail.com |       40      |        3       |
+----+---------------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

**What I've tried**

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, SUM(movies.total_watches) AS total_watches, SUM(sessions.total_time) AS total_time
FROM users
JOIN movies ON users.id = movies.user_id 
JOIN sessions ON users.id = sessions.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id
```

This returns (minus a couple of columns):

```
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
| email            | total_watches |   total_time  |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
| abcdef@gmail.com |       9       |        120    | 
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

**Summary**

I understand that the extra session join creates three rows for every movie and therefore trebles the SUM results, so how do I get the 'flattened' data? I have tried other group by combinations with no luck.

Comment: Your database does not appear to be normalized, because `user_id` appears in _every_ table.  It should not.  By the way, didn't know that there were still people watching Goonies these days.

Comment: You have a typo : `GROUP BY user.id` => `GROUP BY users.id`

Comment: Thanks - typo fixed. Tim: As I mentioned this is hypothetical - the movies table is not actually a list of movies as suggested, I have simplified it for example purposes. PS: Goonies is a classic. Momma....you been baaaaad.

Comment: Either try to do a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your example or provide your real data structure.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments above, your current table structure requires further normalization.

Now, for this table structure, one hacky way is to divide the SUM by Count of rows from the other table (causing duplication due to JOIN), to counter the effect of duplication.

So, the SUM of `total_watches` can be divided by the Count of rows from the `sessions` table for a user id. Similarly, the SUM of `total_time` can be divided by the Count of rows from the `movies` tables.

```
SELECT users.id, 
       SUM(movies.total_watches)/COUNT(DISTINCT sessions.id) AS total_watches, 
       SUM(sessions.total_time)/COUNT(DISTINCT movies.id) AS total_time
FROM users
JOIN movies ON users.id = movies.user_id 
JOIN sessions ON users.id = sessions.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id
```

**Result**

```
| id  | total_watches | total_time |
| --- | ------------- | ---------- |
| 1   | 3             | 40         |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/phox2Wo6c7kjASFP2Fi6qN/0)